# when working in the viewing mode "editing materials" instead of material everything is black

Tags: texturing, materials

Windows 7. Video Card - GtxForce 9500 GT (OpnGl 3.3) .blender version 2.81

when working in the mode of viewing materials instead of material, solid black .
but in mod rendered all ok .
I use diffuse BSDF

---

[image]

but in this mode it works . maybe something with the settings

Comment: Hello, could you add a screenshot of your interface ?

Comment: Your graphics card is below the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/).

Comment: specifications and compliments
I have 1gb video memory
openGl 3.3. 4 ram

Comment: @Gorgious all added photo

Comment: The Nvidia GeForce 9500 GT is from the [GeForce 9 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units#GeForce_9_(9xxx)_series) which predates the [Nvidia GeForce 400 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units#GeForce_400_series). Nvidia GeForce 400 or newer is required for Blender >2.8x.